# How to export a class in a binary file

Tags: c#

I need to export into a binary file an observable collection. This file will be parsed by an embeded software.

This is my class of Led configuration :

```
[XmlRoot("ConfLed")]
public class LedVals
{
    #region Properties
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "Trigger";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Binding { get; set; } = "OFF";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Trigger1 { get; set; } = 0;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Trigger2 { get; set; } = 0;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ColorT0 { get; set; } = "#000000";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ColorT1 { get; set; } = "#000000";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ColorT2 { get; set; } = "#000000";

    #endregion

    public LedVals()
    {

    }

    public LedVals(int idParam, string typeParam, string bindingParam, int trig1Param, int trig2Param, string c0Param, string c1Param, string c2Param)
    {
        this.ID = idParam;
        this.Type = typeParam;
        this.Binding = bindingParam;
        this.Trigger1 = trig1Param;
        this.Trigger2 = trig2Param;
        this.ColorT0 = c0Param;
        this.ColorT1 = c1Param;
        this.ColorT2 = c2Param;
    }
}
```

And this is my serialize function for the observable collection of LedVals class (ListeLedTable) that I need to export:

```
    public void SerializeLedTable(string filePathParam)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream mstream = File.Open(filePathParam + ".bin", FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(mstream, ListeLedTable);
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is a file with binary values of the class properties and text description of the observable collection structure.

Is there a way to export properties values of a class like this ?

I can use a binaryWriter to write each property of my class in a loop, but I thought there might a simpler solution.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Marshal Techniques :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LedVals ledVals = new LedVals();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(ledVals); ;
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(ledVals)];
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(ledVals, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(ledVals));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("FILENAME");
            BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            bWriter.Write(buffer);

        }

    }
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class LedVals
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting a Marshal exception, Marshal.SizeOf can't get the size of a managed object.

Comment: Add before the definition of the class LedVals : [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)].

Comment: If you don't need the file you can use MemoryStream instead.

Comment: The byte order may need to be swapped depending on your embedded software.

Comment: Hi http://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng , I get an AccessViolationException for a protected memory read/write attempt ... on

Comment: Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, true); instruction

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET binary serialization for any interop is a bad idea.

XML might be a better choice, but embedded devices usually lack the required horsepower to do any XML processing. I don't know what your embedded platform is, but there's a chance you could use [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf) ([Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)) to transfer binary data back and forth.

Comment: It is not bad idea.  It is used all the time when sending/receiving to a dll.